# how can i rewrite my url htacceess with GET

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a problem with rewriting my url how can I rewrite this url below :

**http://localhost/Car/index.php?page=allCars&numpage=2**

this is the php and html code for testing

<a href="index.php?page=allCars&numpage=25>

ps : my page all cars is dynamique via index.php with parameter page

---

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /Car/
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Redirect from `localhost/Car/index.php?page=allCars&numpage=2 this to localhost/Car/allCars/25`

Comment: Rewrite it to _what_?

Comment: http://localhost/Car/index.php?page=allCars&numpage=2 this to http://localhost/Car/allCars/25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. These rules assume that your htaccess is present inside Car folder/directory.

```
Options All -Indexes -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /Car/
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
##External rewrite rule.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?page=([^&]*)&numpage=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Car/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
##Internal rewrite rule.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ Car/index.php?page=$1&numpage=$2 [L]
```